# XAML: How do I append a percent symbol to a bound label value?

Tags: xaml, format, label, bind

I have a label bound to the value of a slider.

```
Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Slider}"
```

How do I append a percentage symbol?  The value of the slider is already formatted correctly, so when the value is '50', all I need is '50%'.

I know how to do it in code behind but I was hoping to accomplish this in xaml without creating a converter.  TIA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works fine for me (tested in Kaxaml):

```
<StackPanel>  
  <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" x:Name="slider" />
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider, StringFormat='\{0\}%'}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Without the backslashes I got an error saying that the % character was invalid in that position.

Comment: I changed the label to a TextBlock and it works.  I'll research why a label doesn't allow formatting.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

StringFormat can be used in this format as well

`Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Slider, StringFormat=P2}"`

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and solved it by using this, based on @Wiesel's answer:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=Slider}" 
       ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use StringFormat like so

```
Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Slider, StringFormat='{0}%'}"
```

Comment: Thanks Chris.  I've tried that (and many other configurations) with no luck.  Any thoughts what might be happening?

Comment: That definately works as I have used it myself... What error do you get? What actually gets printed to the screen?

Comment: No error, it simply shows the digits.  ie. '50'  The label has no other properties set.

Comment: Actually...

StringFormat='{0}%'

doesn't work but

StringFormat='{}{0}%'

does?  Strange, that!

That is to say, it shows the digits only.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for WPF >=3.5 SP1:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=Slider}" 
       ContentStringFormat="{0}%" />
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `ContentStringFormat="{}{0}%"`?